# preg_replace returns unexpected results to $1

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<?php
$data='123
[test=abc]cba[/test]
321';
$test = preg_replace("(\[test=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/test\])is","$1",$data);
echo $test;
?>
```

I expect the above code to return 
`abc`
but instead of returning `abc` it returns
`123 abc 321`
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Change it to `$2` since you have two capturing groups and the third one is `$0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only replacing the matched part (the BBcode section). You're leaving the rest of the string untouched.

If you also want to remove the leading/trailing text, include those in the expression:

```
$test = preg_replace("(.*\[test=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/test\].*)is","$1",$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of this, but the outermost set of parentheses in your regex does not form a group (capturing or otherwise).   PHP is interpreting them as [regex delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  If you *are* aware of that, and you're using them as delimiters on purpose, please don't.  It's usually best to use a non-bracketing character that never has any special meaning in regexes (`~`, `%`, `@`, etc.).

I agree with [Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327804/20938) that `preg_match()` is the tool you should be using, not `preg_replace()`.  But his solution is trickier than it needs to be.  Your original regex works fine; all you have to do is grab the contents of the first capturing group, like so:

```
if (preg_match('%\[test=(.+?)\](.+?)\[/test\]%si', $data, $match)) {
    $test = $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a replace here, all that you need is to take something in the string. To do that preg_match is more useful:

```
$data='123
[test=abc]cba[/test]
321';
$test = preg_match('~\[test=\K[^\]]++~', $data, $match);
echo $match[0];
```